# Overlay image on R leaflet map

Tags: python, r, leaflet

I have a .PNG image which fundamentally represents is raster, but is not in a raster format. These are provide to me, otherwise I would generate them as rasters myself and avoid this problem.

I would like to overlay the image on a leaflet basemap in R. The image overlay will just provide a reference for the user to draw a bounding box around a region, and query a database for the raw data that generated the raster in that region.

In Python's implementation of leaflet the image overlay is possible in this manner

```
center = [0,0]
zoom = 2

m = Map(center=center, zoom=zoom)
layer = ImageOverlay(url="filename.png", bounds=(( min_lat, min_lon), 
                                             (max_lat, max_lon)))
m.add_layer(layer)
return m
```

Thus far it looks like to do this in R, I need a raster object that then use `addRasterImage()`, which appears to converts the raster to a RGB image and then overlays it on the leaflet map. I have an image initially and just want add it as a layer rather than a requiring a raster format. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to append the image and not change it afterwards (bbox or source), then you should be able to do that using htmlwidgets to access native leaflet.js:

> The htmlwidget::onRender function can be used to add custom behavior
>   to the leaflet map using native Javascript. This is a some what
>   advanced use case and requires you to know Javascript. Using onRender
>   you can customize your map’s behavior using any of the APIs as defined
>   in the Leaflet.js documentation. (from leaflet r [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/morefeatures.html))

This gives you a bit more flexibility by revealing the more extensive native functionality. To add an image overlay is rather straightforward ([example](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#imageoverlay)) and similar to the python implementation. A simple example adopted from the r and js documentation versions might look like:

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=-74.22655, lat=40.712216, popup="Bottom Right Corner") %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender("
      function(el, x) {
        console.log(this);
        var myMap = this;
        var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg';
        var imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];

        L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(myMap);
      }
      ")
m  # Print the map
```