# How to add group name when adding overlay images in leaflet(R)?

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

I want to overlay an image on the leaflet map in R, and found a good example from [Overlay image on R leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170828/overlay-image-on-r-leaflet-map)  . 
Here is Andrew Reid's example code:

```
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=-74.22655, lat=40.712216, popup="Bottom Right Corner") %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender("
      function(el, x) {
        console.log(this);
        var myMap = this;
        var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg';
        var imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];

        L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(myMap);
      }
      ")
m  # Print the map
```

My question is how to add group name of this image layer so that I can Show/Hide Layers in the leaflet map like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l18q.png) (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to make the image interacive and change its opacity when clicking on it:

```
      let vis = 0.95
      let img = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {opacity:vis, interactive: true});
      img.on('click', function(d) {
            vis = 1-vis;
            this.setOpacity(vis);
      });

      img.addTo(myMap)
```